# Por que declarar ponteiro para array se arrays já são ponteiros?

Tags: c, array, ponteiro

se um array  char já é um ponteiro, por que declarar um ponteiro para o array?

E qual é a diferença entre `char exemplo[10]` e `char *exemplo[10]`?

Comment: Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: Quando estudei C eu tive esta dúvida tbm, mas hoje em dia tenho consciea da necessidade de se apontar para um ponteiro

Answer (score 8):

Você **não** está declarando um ponteiro para *array*. Está declarando um ponteiro para `char`. Ao contrário da crença popular, eles são [coisas distintas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101).

No primeiro exemplo tem um *array* com 10 `char`s. No segundo tem um *array* com 10 ponteiros para `char`.

O ponteiro para `char` é praticamente um sinônimo para *string*. A linguagem C não tem o tipo *string*, mas isto é o mais próximo de uma.

Obviamente o ponteiro precisa apontar para uma área da memória que tenha uma sequência de `char`s.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Um literal entre aspas, em C, tem tipo array de `N` caracteres em que `N` é o suficiente para os caracteres do literal e o terminador. `"exemplo"` tem tipo `char [8]`.

Comment: @pmg é verdade, ele decai para um `const char *` apenas. Consertei isso.

Comment: Quando é usado como valor, o array é convertido para um ponteiro para o seu primeiro elemento. No caso de string literais esta conversão é para o tipo `char *` (não `const char *`) embora o resultado seja *read-only*. Para evitar surpresas muita gente acrescenta o `const` especificamente.

Answer (score 7):

Um array char (ou outro tipo) **NÃO É** um ponteiro.

Um array é um array; um ponteiro é um ponteiro (ver [secção 6 do c-faq](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html)).

Quando um array é usado como valor, ele é convertido para um ponteiro para o seu primeiro elemento.

A diferença entre `char exemplo[10]` e `char *exemplo[10]` é que o primeiro declara um array de 10 caracteres e o segundo declara um array de 10 ponteiros.

Comment: +1 pelo "Um array char (ou outro tipo) NÃO É um ponteiro". 
Tenho visto várias respostas que indicam: na linguagem C arrays não existem de verdade, ou que são o mesmo que apontadores.