# Como funcionam os ponteiros do C?

Tags: c, ponteiro

**1º** Qual a diferença entre declarar: `char* s` e `char *s`?

**2º** É sempre necessário usar a função `malloc` sempre que declarar um *pointer*?

*Exemplo:*

```
 char* s = malloc(sizeof(char));

 //ou apenas...

 char* s;
```

**3º** Declarar um ponteiro `char* s` é como se eu estivesse declarando uma `string`? Posso usar isso como uma `String`?

**4º** Exemplo:

```
char* s;
char s;
```

Qual a diferença entre elas?

**5º** Qual a real utilidade de `ponteiros`? Além de resolver alguns *bugs*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Qual a diferença entre declarar: char* s e char *s?

Nenhuma. Estética, apenas. É menos confuso escrever:

`char *s, *r` do que `char* s, *r`, p.e.

> 2º É sempre necessário usar a função malloc sempre que declarar um pointer?

Não, você está confundindo as coisas. Um ponteiro nada mais é que uma
variável que armazena um endereço. Da mesma forma que um inteiro aramazena
um número. Como os diversos tipos (int, char, etc) tem tamanhos diferentes,
existe um ponteiro diferente para cada tipo. Isso ocorre por causa de
aritmética com ponteiros, que explico depois.

```
char c = 'a';
char *s = &a;
```

O código acima declara uma variável `c` que armazena um caracter e uma variável
`s` que armazena o endereço de `c`.  Podíamos ainda criar uma variável para
armazenar o endereço de
`s`:

```
char **ss = &s;
```

Ficando:

```
Variável    Endereço (hipotético)     Valor     Tamanho
c           0x0002                    'a'       sizeof(char) bytes
s           0x0010                    0x0002    sizeof(char *) bytes
ss          0xFF10                    0x0010    sizeof(char **) bytes
```

malloc é uma função que reserva um espaço contínuo de memória no heap,
retornando o endereço do início desse espaço (do tipo ponteiro, pois é um
endereço). P.e.

```
char *s = malloc(2);
```

Reserva dois bytes, e o endereço inicial é atribuido para a variável s:

```
Variável    Endereço (hipotético)     Valor     Tamanho
s           0x0001                    ?         2 bytes
```

Se formos imprimir:

```
printf("%p\n", s + 1);
```

Veremos `0x0002`, o endereço de s mais um. Isso porque o tamanho de `char` é
1 byte (`s + 1` traduz para `sizeof(*s) + 1`). Por essa questão aritmética
(usada em arrays, entre outras coisas) é que cada tipo tem um "tipo ponteiro"
equivalente, inclusive ponteiros de ponteiros de ponteiros de ...

> 3º Declarar uma variável char* s é como se eu estivesse declarando uma
>   string? Posso usar isso como uma String?

Não. `char *s` contém um endereço. Ponto. Uma string é uma array de caracteres,
que pode ser declarada de várias formas (pesquise sobre quando usar malloc, ou
faça uma pergunta nova, e leia o manual sobre o uso do malloc):

```
char *s = malloc(10 * sizeof(*s));
char s2[10];
strncpy(s, "123456789", 10);
strncpy(s2, "123456789", 10);
char s3[] = "123456789";
char *s4 = strdup("123456789");
free(s);
free(s4);
```

Leia o manual das funções supracitadas se quiser entender mais sobre elas. Em
Linux/OSX: `man FUNCAO`.

> char* s; char s;

Como já foi explicado, um guarda um caractere e o outro um endereço.

> 5º Qual a real utilidade de pointers? Além de resolver alguns bugs?

Talvez essa resposta tenha dado uma ideia inicial sobre ponteiros. São usados
para absolutamente tudo, como você verá quando for aprendendo mais.

Answer (score 13):

A pergunta é muito ampla, deveria ser separada, mas vamos lá:

> Qual a diferença entre declarar: `char* s` e `char *s`?

Nenhuma, é gosto.

> É sempre necessário usar a função `malloc()` sempre que declarar um *pointer*?

Não, mas sempre que declarar um ponteiro, é provável que em algum momento vai ter que colocar um valor lá. Na maior parte das vezes será direta ou indiretamente através do [`malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), ênfase para o indireto. Mas é possível apontar para outras áreas da memória, como a [`stack`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) (geralmente pela criação de um *array* ou estrutura, mas em tese qualquer endereço pode ser usado bastando usar o operador `&` para pegar o endereço) ou a área estática, inclusive, onde estão os métodos (ponteiro para função). O `malloc()` é usado para alocar memória no [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

> Declarar um ponteiro `char* s` é como se eu estivesse declarando uma *string*? Posso usar isso como uma *string*?

Grosso modo podemos dizer que sim, mas C não tem um tipo *string* nativo, não é exatamente a mesma coisa.

> Exemplo: `char* s;` e `char s;` Qual a diferença entre elas?

O primeiro é um ponteiro para um caractere, inclusive pode haver uma sequência deles a partir daquele ponto da memória, o programador deve controlar isto. O segundo é apenas um caractere.

> Qual a real utilidade de ponteiros? Além de resolver alguns *bugs*?

Ponteiros não resolvem *bugs*. Isto é insano. Ponteiro é um endereço para algum ponto da memória, só isto. Ele é usado para indicar onde estão certos objetos. Ter acesso à memória de forma indireta. Como o nome diz, ele serve para apontar para coisas em outro lugar.

Pode ser melhor respondido em diversas perguntas aqui, por isso não dei mais detalhes:

- [Qual a diferença entre ponteiro e referência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101)
- [Arrays são ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101)
- [Por que declarar ponteiro para array se arrays já são ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91297/101)
- [O que é ponteiro para ponteiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92823/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Sobre o item 4, muito bem descrito. Geralmente as pessoas tendem a não explicar corretamente a diferença.