# Porque a expressão "$a->b->c->d->e->f->g->h->i->j =& $null;" retorna vários objetos dentro do outro, sendo que ele nem existe?

Tags: php, objetos

Eu estava fazendo uns testes com atribuições de valores por referências em PHP e me deparei com um exemplo curioso.

```
$a->b->c->d->e->f->g->h->i->j =& $null;
```

Tanto as variáveis `$a` e `Null` não existem em nenhum escopo do meu script.

Quando dou um `print_r($a)`, veja o que é retornado:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [b] => stdClass Object
        (
            [c] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [d] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [e] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [f] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [g] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [h] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [i] => stdClass Object
                                                                (
                                                                    [j] => 
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

https://ideone.com/zvaLkJ

O estranho é que, quando eu tento fazer isso sem referência, olha o que acontece:

```
$a->b->c = 1;
```

> PHP Warning: Creating default object from empty value on line 1

Por que acontece isso em PHP? Qual é o motivo desse comportamento (o objeto ser criado do nada e não ter emitido nenhum Warning)?

Por que as variáveis `$a` e `$null` não retornaram `Undefined variable` quando eu usei referências?

Comment: Só faltou a imagem do Ryu dando um hadouken no resultado do `array`

Comment: @BrunoCosta pior que não é, há uma explicação. Só estou aguardando alguém que explique melhor do que aquilo que já sei

Comment: Galera, ninguém se arrisca a responder essa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente você tem coisas diferentes:

- No primeiro caso você esta atribuindo uma referencia a um objeto, em suma é isso que ele é, uma referencia, não importa o que tiver la, ele só "aposta".
- O segundo caso é uma atribuição direta, você deseja reservar um local na memoria para para atribuir um valor.

#### Erro

O erro causado é um "warning" (aviso/alerta).

> PHP Warning: Creating default object from empty value on line 1

Quer disser que você quer atribuir o valor em um "*atributo*"(objeto), sendo que nem objeto tem ainda, para isso ele necessitou criar um objeto *defaulf*.

#### Adendo

Note que se você fizer :

```
$b->c = 6;

$a->b =& $b;

var_dump($a->b);
```

O *warning* é disparado no `$b`, e no `$a->b` ele só retomou a referencia nele guardada.

## E por que usando referências não deu erro?

Para entender o comportamento exemplificado, primeiro temos que analisar com calma o que está escrito no Manual do PHP, referente a *Atribuição por referência*.

> **Nota:**
> Se você atribuir, passar ou retornar uma variável indefinida por referência, ela irá ser criada.

E acrescento: *Se você atribuir, passar ou retornar uma variável indefinida por referência, ela será criada, e **setada** para `NULL`*

Ou seja, se você utilizar o sinal de atribuição por referência (`=&`) para uma variável que não exista, a mesma será criada.

Para analisar, faça o teste:

```
$a =& $b;

$c =& $d;

var_dump(get_defined_vars());
```

O resultado será:

```
['a' => NULL, 'b' => NULL, 'c' => NULL, 'd' => NULL]
```

Outra prova de que a afirmação acima está correta pode ser vista para quem já utilizou as funções `preg_match` ou `parse_str`. As mesmas utilizam referências para trazer o resultado da função (ao invés de `return`), mesmo que a variável não exista, ela passa a existir.

Exemplo:

```
 preg_match('/eu_amo_regex/', 'eu_amo_regex_sim', $vou_passar_a_existir);

 print_r($vou_passar_a_existir);// Essa foi criada na passagem do argumento
```

Veja no esqueleto da função a referência no `3` parâmetro:

```
int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int  $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

No seu caso, o atributo `j` do objeto será `NULL`, e a variável `$null` também. Toda a estrutura do objeto é criada, pois você está usando referência, por isso não dá erro.

Pergunta relacionada : [Como funcionam os ponteiros do C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106227/14213)

Comment: kkk, eu já ia responder. Posso adicionar uma informação importantísima na resposta?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters a vontade, o conteúdo aqui é pub :D.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters como você acrescentou 2/3 da resposta deixei como wiki :D