# Dúvida em relação a ponteiros em C

Tags: c, string, ponteiro, for

```
void imprime (char *v, int n) {
   char *c;
   for (c = v; c < v + n; v++)
      printf ("%c", *c);
}
```

Tenho essa função, mas não entendi o que ela exatamente está fazendo e como os ponteiros se comportam nesse caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está recebendo uma *string* (`char *` é um ponteiro para caracteres, em C é assim que se costuma representar textos), e um inteiro.

Declara uma outra *string* `c` sem conteúdo algum.

Inicia um laço colocando o ponteiro do parâmetro `v` em `c`, então ambas apontam para o mesmo objeto.

O laço terminará quando `c` for igual ao endereço de `v` mais `n` bytes/caracteres.

Há um incremento em `v` em cada passada do laço. Na minha opinião há um erro aí. Acho que o incremento deveria ser em `c`.

Será impresso o caractere indicado por `c`. O `*` é usado porque você quer o conteúdo contido no endereço `c` e não o seu valor que é um endereço de memória. Ponteiros sempre funcionam assim.

Em resumo, se o algoritmo estivesse correto iria imprimir caractere por caractere tantos quantos indicados em `n`. Se `n` for maior que o tamanho da *string* vai pegar lixo da memória. Ou seja, mais um problema no algoritmo.

Compreendo o exercício, mas isso é desnecessário já que o o próprio [`printf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) é capaz de imprimir uma quantidade de caracteres estabelecido na formatação.

Estou respondendo o que pede a pergunta. Sei que alguns conceitos apresentados podem não estar claros para quem está começando. Precisa pesquisar sobre eles ou fazer novas perguntas.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/B4idfZ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/euhkjrye-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/PrintString.c).

Se quiser saber mais tem algumas perguntas sobre o assunto:

- [Quando devo escolher entre utilizar ou não um ponteiro ao criar um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50165/101)
- [Como funcionam os ponteiros do C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106227/101)
- [Arrays são ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101)

Answer (score 1):

Esta função recebe de parâmetro um ponteiro para caractere e uma quantidade. Assume-se que esse ponteiro aponta para um array de caracteres, de tamanho, no mínimo, igual à quantidade informada.

Na inicialização do `for`, é feito com que a variável de ponteiro `c` aponte para o array. Na memória, teríamos algo como:

```
|A|l|ô| |M|u|n|d|o|
 ^
 c
```

`c` está apontando para o primeiro caractere do array. Fazendo-se `*c` é possível acessar este caractere.

A cada iteração do `for`, `c` é incrementado. O que acontece é que ele passa a apontar para o próximo elemento do array:

```
|A|l|ô| |M|u|n|d|o|
   ^                 segunda iteração
   c

|A|l|ô| |M|u|n|d|o|
     ^               terceira iteração
     c

...

|A|l|ô| |M|u|n|d|o|
                 ^   última iteração
                 c
```

No seu exemplo, a cada iteração um caractere é lido e impresso no console utilizando a função `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Esta função imprime n caracteres a partir do endereço apontado pelo ponteiro "v", mas em sua pergunta o código está errado, onde está "v++" deve ser "c++", como abaixo.

Inicialmente "c" tem o mesmo valor de "v". A cada iteração do "for" o ponteiro "c" avança uma posição, e imprime o próximo caracter. O loop termina quando "c" se torna igual a "v + n", tendo impresso n caracteres.

```
void imprime (char *v, int n)
{
   char *c;
   for (c = v; c < v + n; c++)
       printf ("%c", *c);
   }
```